# How to migrate data from foreign key in unmanaged model to managed model in Django 1.7?

Tags: django, django-models

We're slowly moving from unmanaged to managed models, one foreign key at a time. The current situation:

```
class OldOrg(Model):
    pass

    class Meta:
        managed = False

class OldService(Model):
    offered_by = models.ForeignKey(OldOrg)

    class Meta:
        managed = False

class NewOrg(Model):
    org = models.OneToOneKey(OldOrg)

class NewService(Model):
    service = OneToOneKey(OldService)
```

The next step:

```
class NewService(Model):
    service = OneToOneKey(OldService)
    offered_by = models.ForeignKey(NewOrg)
```

The problem happens in the data migration using django's inbuilt migration system. The field `OldService.offered_by` does not exist, so we cannot use that to get to the `NewOrg` primary key for use in `NewService.offered_by`.

```
# This works in the shell but not in a migration
for ns in NewService.objects.all():
   ns.offered_by = ns.service.offered_by.new_org
```

In the migration, `OldService` doesn't have the field `offered_by_id` either. Is there some other way to get at the data in `OldService`?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution, but I don't like it:

Use as raw SQL as possible in the migration:

```
from django.db import connection

def copy_org(apps, schema_editor):
    NewService = apps.get_model('myapp', 'NewService')
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute('SELECT id, offered_by FROM myapp_old_service')
        old_services = dict(cursor.fetchall())
    for ns in NewService.objects.all():
        ns.offered_by = old_services[ns.pk]
        ns.save()
```